# Creating custom row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I create the resulting row? Something like this

[image]

Comment: What kind of application ? winform ? asp.net ? wpf ?, if its Winform see: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51889/Summary-DataGridView

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVDxuz_av7A

Comment: yes it's winform. thank you